# vue-router useRouter doesn't work when building library components

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-router

I am building a Vue3 npm component library with hopes that I could access the current router with vue-router's `useRouter`, and it would be automatically provided by whatever vue app is importing my library components.

If my library components are referenced directly `import myCompThatUsesRouter from '../../myCompThatUsesRouter.vue` the router works.

If I reference the same component via the node_module package `import myCompThatUsesRouter from '@myPackage'` router is `undefined`.

I also get a vue warning

> injection "Symbol()" not found.

Is this not how these inject methods are intended to work?

Answer (score 5):

The issue was that my library defined vue-router as a "dependency", not a "peerDependency".
https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

Also my vite config needed to define vue-router as "external"

vite.config.ts

```
rollupOptions: {
   external: ['vue', 'vue-router']
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue in my case, thanks!

Comment: When I used my library's router component in a Nuxt 3 app it seemed to work fine, adding vue-router as an external did seem to be required when importing it into a vue 3 project though. Thanks.